# Removing entries from a HashMap based on value

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I've written the following code ([+ demo](http://is.gd/weRHua)) to remove entries from a `HashMap` based on value. *It works, but I feel like I'm struggling against the borrow-checker* with the use of:

- `clone()` to avoid two references to the same set of keys
- an extra `let tmp =` binding to increase the lifetime of my temp value

---

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn strip_empties(x: &mut HashMap<String, i8>) {
    let tmp = x.clone();
    let empties = tmp
         .iter()
         .filter(|&(_, &v)| v == 0)
         .map(|(k, _)| k);

    for k in empties { x.remove(k); }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x: HashMap<String, i8> = HashMap::new();
    x.insert("a".to_string(), 1);
    x.insert("b".to_string(), 0);
    strip_empties(&mut x);

    println!("Now down to {:?}" , x);
}
```

Is there a cleaner, more idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 56):

The other answers are outdated. As of Rust 1.27, you can use [`HashMap::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.retain) to keep only the elements you are interested in. You specify the elements to keep using a closure.

```
x.retain(|_, v| *v != 0);
```

Comment: An example showing how to solve the problem in OPs code would go a long way to making this a good answer.

Comment: meta question: is there a way to somehow push a more updated answer to the top? e.g., perhaps changing this to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 16):

Why the mutation of the HashMap? Just create a new one (all hail immutability):

```
fn strip_empties(x: HashMap<String, i8>) -> HashMap<String, i8> {
    return x.into_iter()
        .filter(|&(_, v)| v != 0)
        .collect();
}
```

[Playpen](http://is.gd/7lbr9d)

---

### Edit: Why this is feasible.

Of course you have to consider your use case. The best approach may vary if
you have a large HashMap or filter many/few elements. Lets compare the
implementations.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn strip_empties_mutable(x: &mut HashMap<String, i8>) {
    let empties: Vec<_> = x
        .iter()
        .filter(|&(_, &v)| v == 0)
        .map(|(k, _)| k.clone())
        .collect();
    for empty in empties { x.remove(&empty); }
}

fn strip_empties_immutable(x: HashMap<String, i8>) -> HashMap<String, i8> {
    return x.into_iter()
        .filter(|&(_, v)| v != 0)
        .collect();
}

fn build_hashmap() -> HashMap<String, i8> {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    for chr in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvmxyz".chars() {
        map.insert(chr.to_string(), chr as i8 % 2);
    }
    return map;
}

#[cfg(mutable)]
fn main() {
    let mut map = build_hashmap();
    strip_empties_mutable(&mut map);
    println!("Now down to {:?}" , map);
}

#[cfg(immutable)]
fn main() {
    let mut map = build_hashmap();
    map = strip_empties_immutable(map);
    println!("Now down to {:?}" , map);
}
```

Save this as `hashmap.rs` and run:

```
rustc --cfg mutable -O -o mutable hashmap.rs
rustc --cfg immutable -O -o immutable hashmap.rs
```

If we look at the different runtimes (e.g. using `perf stat -r 1000 ./XXX`) we
don't see significant differences.

But lets look at the number of allocations:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=callgrind_mutable ./mutable
valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=callgrind_immutable ./immutable
callgrind_annotate callgrind_mutable | grep 'je_.*alloc'
callgrind_annotate callgrind_immutable | grep 'je_.*alloc'
```

- callgrind_mutable:

  ```
  7,000  ???:je_arena_malloc_small [$HOME/hashmap/mutable]
  6,457  ???:je_arena_dalloc_bin_locked [$HOME/hashmap/mutable]
  4,800  ???:je_mallocx [$HOME/hashmap/mutable]
  3,903  ???:je_sdallocx [$HOME/hashmap/mutable]
  2,520  ???:je_arena_dalloc_small [$HOME/hashmap/mutable]
    502  ???:je_rallocx [$HOME/hashmap/mutable]
    304  ???:je_arena_ralloc [$HOME/hashmap/mutable]
  ```
- callgrind_immutable:

  ```
  5,114  ???:je_arena_malloc_small [$HOME/hashmap/immutable]
  4,725  ???:je_arena_dalloc_bin_locked [$HOME/hashmap/immutable]
  3,669  ???:je_mallocx [$HOME/hashmap/immutable]
  2,980  ???:je_sdallocx [$HOME/hashmap/immutable]
  1,845  ???:je_arena_dalloc_small [$HOME/hashmap/immutable]
    158  ???:je_rallocx [$HOME/hashmap/immutable]
  ```

And this is not very suprising as the `clone()` calls in the mutable approach
allocates memory aswell. Of course the mutable version might yield a HashMap
with a larger capacity.

Comment: While this looks really nice on paper, it'll involve a lot of deallocations and allocations for the HashMap entries. That's why a mutation might be preferable.

Comment: I think it will only involve one allocation and deallocation (for the whole backing table).

Comment: Can you give me a sense of why you call this "immutable", when it consumes (destroys) the source hashmap? I understand the approach and like it -- but I'm trying to figure out why "immutable" is the right word for it.

Comment: @Bosh In this case the source HashMap is destroyed, yes. But it could be retained in it's original form if another variable was used. So it's immutable as the original HashMap is not mutated.

Comment: @lummax: My understanding is that even if you used another variable, as in `let mut stripped_map = strip_empties_immutable(map);`, the original `map` variable would no longer be usable, because of the behavior of `into_iter` (which consumes the thing). Is that right?

Comment: @Bosh: Of course. The `into_iter()` is consuming (`strip_empties()` is consuming). But that could easily be changed into a reference. This is about if it's ok to construct a new Hashmap.

Comment: What about usage of `drain` for inplace filter?

Comment: There's now a tracking issue to add drain_filter to HashMap. It's not merged at time of writing but might be soon: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/59618

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to delete values from hashmap during iteration (neither via `remove`, neither via `Entry` api) because of borrowing restrictions, so your idea (collecting keys to remove) is pretty close to the right solution.

You just don't need to clone the whole hash table, it is sufficient to collect only key copies:

```
fn strip_empties(x: &mut HashMap<String, i8>) {
    let empties: Vec<_> = x
         .iter()
         .filter(|&(_, &v)| v == 0)
         .map(|(k, _)| k.clone())
         .collect();
    for empty in empties { x.remove(&empty); }
}
```

Comment: This raises the interesting question why `HashMap` does not have an iterator that returns `Entry` (or `(Key, Entry)` tuples). I can't see any reason why this should not be possible. Does anyone know if this is just a case of "Well, no-one has bothered to implement it yet"?

Comment: `HashMap`'s `iter` function (as used above) *does* create an iterator over `Key, Entry` tuples. I may be misunderstanding your question...

Comment: Different "Entry". fjh is talking about std::collections::hash_map::Entry and I have the same question. I think Bosh is just using the word Entry generically to mean the value in the map.